# Using Zod to check for alphanumeric value

Tags: javascript, validation, zod

I know I can combine Validator.js with Zod to check if an input is alphanumeric. However, is there a built-in way with Zod to check for alphanumeric **WITHOUT** having to use regex?

Comment: Doesn’t look like it. There’s many definitions of what alpha numeric could mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zod does not have those, because their regex implementation is straightforward (unlike email or IP(it checks for numbers to be 0-255)), and if implementation for your case is not it recommends using validator.JS (e.g. language-dependent alphanumeric)